# How to validate a required field? Throw exception in setter?

Tags: validation, jsf, setter, managed-bean

Is it possible to throw a exception from a managed bean setter?

For example i would create a setter like:

```
public void setName(String _name) throws Exception{
    if(_name.compareTo("")==0)
        throw new Exception("Name is empty!");

    name=_name;
}
```

If I would now try to submit a form with an empty name-field it should display "Name is empty!".

I know I could handle this inside the action method of my form but the solution above seems to be better practise to me.

Comment: Have you actually tried it? Also use .equals() when comparing strings and always use the String constant (" ") first as it is never null..... (" ").equals(_name)

Comment: This is pretty much unacceptable. Simply delegating this functionality to JSF validators is sufficient.

Comment: I know that it wouldn't work this way, I just wanted to make my problem a little bit clearer.

Comment: I suggest to take a pause on the current project and go get a sane JSF book and work through it in order to properly grasp the essential basics.

Comment: I only got 1 more week to finish this project.. so no time for reading books :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're supposed to use JSF builtin validation facilities. In your case you better use the `required` and `requiredMessage` attributes.

Something like this:

```
<h:inputText id="name" value="#{myBean.name}" required="true" 
    requiredMessage="Name is empty!"/>
<h:message for="name" />
```

Comment: What if I want to include some other kind of validation?

Comment: If you want to use some other validation then `validator` tag can indeed to useful, but for the described above issue the `required` and `requiredMessage` attributes are good enough

Comment: Is there anything else to do except adding the required and requiredMessage attributes? I don't get any messages on saving empty fields..

Comment: needed to add a messag field too